# Operating on a file with a very specific format

Tags: python, python-3.5, atom-editor

I have been trying to write the following function:

```
def track(filepath,n1,n2)
```

This function is meant to operate on a file with the following format:

```
-BORDER-
text
-BORDER-
text
-BORDER-
text
-BORDER-
```

How do I tell the function to operate on this file path and more precisely on the text inside each border?

Comment: Is your file a `.txt` file ? and is there always only one text line between your Border lines ?

Comment: yes, but between the  border lines i would always have more text lines

Comment: If i get it : you might have many text lines between your Border lines and your Border lines are all the same ?

Comment: yeah, the start and the end of the text is marked by a line which contains only the word -BORDER-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a generator, that counts detect border lines and use `groupby` to separate these blocks:

```
from itertools import groupby

BORDER = '--border--'

def count_border(lines, border):
  cnt = 0
  for line in lines:
    if line.strip() == border:
        cnt += 1
    else:
        yield cnt, line

with open('file') as lines:
    for _, block in groupby(count_border(lines, BORDER), lambda (c,_): c):
        block = [line for _, line in block]
        print(block)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following approach would read your file in, and give you a list of non border lines:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open('input.txt') as f_input:
    for k, g in groupby(f_input, lambda x: not x.startswith('-BORDER-')):
        if k:
            print([line.strip() for line in g])
```

So if your input file was:

```
-BORDER-
text
-BORDER-
text
-BORDER-
this is some text
with words 
on different lines
-BORDER-
```

It would display the following output:

```
['text']
['text']
['this is some text', 'with words', 'on different lines']
```

This works by reading your file in line by line, and using Python's [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby) function to group lines matching a given test. In this case the test is whether or not the line starts `-BORDER-`. It returns all following lines which return the same result. The `k` is the test result, and the `g` is the group of matching lines. So if the test result is `True`, it means it did not start with `-BORDER-`.

Next, as each of your lines has a newline, a list comprehension is used to strip this from each of the returned lines.

---

If you wanted to count the words (assuming they are delimited by spaces) then you could do the following:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open('input.txt') as f_input:
    for k, g in groupby(f_input, lambda x: not x.startswith('-BORDER-')):
        if k:
            lines = list(g)
            word_count = sum(len(line.split()) for line in lines)
            print("{} words in {}".format(word_count, lines))
```

Giving you:

```
1 words in ['text\n']
1 words in ['text\n']
9 words in ['this is some text\n', 'with words \n', 'on different lines\n']
```

Comment: and how do i operate on the -BORDER- text -BORDER- of the file?

Comment: If you take the `if` line out, it will show you all lines grouped. Or if you take the `not` out, it would only work on the `-BORDER-` lines. Alternatively, you could add an `else` line to the `if`.

Comment: could i also count words that match given property in each "paragraph" or in all the paragraphs?

Comment: I have added a suitable example to the answer to help get you started.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the text from your text file you can do as follows :

```
with open("/your/path/to/file", 'r') as f:
    text_list = [line for line in f.readlines() if 'BORDER' not in line]
```

`text_list` will contain all the text lines you are looking for. You can, if needed, strip the lines using `.strip()`

Comment: you can also strip the line in the list comprehension, but I don't know how the strip would look like. I guess the line might end with a `'\n'`.

Comment: if i already have my file in one of my pc directories, is it better to "load" the file or not?

Comment: What do you mean by 'load' it ? You can just read it using the context manager `with open(...) as f `

Comment: don't mind, i I got mixed up